# Subtracting Date/Time from two different tables in SQL

Tags: ssms

I have two tables with a time column (year-day-month hr:min:sec)

Let's say name of table 1 is plc and column name Collect 
Name of table2 is Adm and column name Disc

I want to subtract the time of Collect (2005-01-03 18:10:05) from the disc column (2005-01-03 20:15:10) in day, hours, minutes.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to google "subtract time in sql"?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Date/time functionality can be database-specific.

Comment: Thanks, changed the tag. Using sql management studio. I tried the code below and came back with an error code. convert (varchar, (adm.disc - plc.collect), 108).

Comment: In most cases, time problems can be resolved from UTC time and/or timestamps. Do not forget 1pm here, is not 1pm everywhere on the planet! If you convert both dates into a same base time, then you can perform comparitions or subtract .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would surely go for the datediff function.
Have a look at this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794(v=sql.90).aspx

If you want, you can select difference in minutes, and then, with the minutes, calculate the days and hours

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date()` or `Datepart()` function to fetch the specific part of the date and subtract the two.

You can get more details of the above two at the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql